# Add contextual link to a view block

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I would like to add a link to the contextual links on a view block. Currently there's the "modify view" and "translate view" links.

Isn't there a way to inject it in the myTheme.theme file ? Like a preprocess ? I looked in the preprocess_view_view and there's only this in the title_suffix :

```
"contextual_links" =>
   "#type" => "contextual_links_placeholder"
   "#id" => "entity.view.edit_form:view=promotions:location=block&name=promotions&display_id=block_1&langcode=fr"
```

I want to add "Sort" that links to "/admin/sort/promotions".

I searched a bit and all I see is solutions talking about creating a custom module. I tried but it's way over my head with the routing and all... I just don't get it. Seems I would need to learn Drupal 8 inside out just to add that link.